# Reinstalling Windows from Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, reinstall

I'm kinda new to Ubuntu.

I have 2 operating systems, Windows 7 on partition C and Ubuntu 14 on partition D. I need to reinstall Windows, wiping only partition C (I need to preserve all files on D). I don't have an installation disc or USB for Windows, only an `.iso` image. Is it possible to reinstall Windows with this? How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Can you boot on the Ubuntu on your `D:\` partition ? If so, just launch GParted and format your `C:\` partition.

Then write your image of windows on an USB stick and boot on it.

You just have to follow the installation and choose the deleted partition.

You will probably need an other USB stick with Ubuntu on it to recreate the grub.

Follow this [procedure](https://askubuntu.com/a/6321/425778).

Comment: i don't have usb stick anywhere around, is there anoither way? like daemon tools for windows?